# Не авторизует пользователя в джанго

Tags: django, django-view

Я создал две пользовательские формы на основе UserCreationForm и AuthenticationForm. После регистрации пользователя я хочу сразу его авторизовать, и мне это удалось. Но когда я просто хочу войти в систему, появляется ошибка {'invalid_login': 'Пожалуйста, введите правильный %(имя пользователя) и пароль. Обратите внимание, что оба поля могут быть чувствительны к регистру.', 'inactive': 'Эта учетная запись неактивна.'}, даже если все введенные данные верны.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='accounts/images', default='default/user.jpg', blank=True, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=130, null=True, blank=True)
date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f"{self.username}, {self.email}"
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password']
    
labels = {
    'username': "Username",
    'password': 'Password'
}
```

views.py

```
class LoginView(View):

def get(self, request):
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print(f"User {username} login successfully.")
            return redirect('blog:index')
        
    print(f"Form errors: {form.error_messages}")
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
```

template login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Login user
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```